# Scrolling effect in ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit

How can I achieve when the user scrolls in the ViewController down to make the highlighted text show up in NavigationBar and when the user scrolls back up to make it disappear again? Similar to Apple's one in Settings app in Apple advertising (https://i.stack.imgur.com/guZ1C.jpg)

[image]

Comment: There's no public API for that, so doing it would involve some tricky programming.

Comment: instead of using a scroll view a workaround would be to add a table view and create a cell which will auto adjust its height and set the title as table section  header . So when the content get scrolled the title part will sat at the same space

Comment: @matt Not everything needs a dedicated public API. This is achievable using a combination of regular public API's without much tricky programming.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
Looking at the image you posted, this seems to be the default transition a large style navigation bar gives you. The only tweak that's been done is centering the title text.

Original answer:
The text in the navigation bar follows the `.title` property of your view controller. However, setting the title is not animated. Depending on your use case, that may or may not be enough.

If you want to do things a bit more fancy, you have some control over the `.navigationItem.titleView` in a view controller. This way you can use a custom view in the navigation bar. Using this, and a bit of fancy programming, you can animate things there.

Last, you can read the scroll position of a `UITableView` or a `UIScrollView` by implementing the scroll view's delegate's `scrollViewDidScroll` method. How you know where the labels that are interesting are depends on the content of your scrollView, so I can't answer that for you.